Sorting a linked list keeping some elements packed together
I have a linked list:
MyLinkedList::LinkedList<Event *> list;

where LinkedList comes from this library, and Event is this struct:
typedef struct 
{
    TimeSpan time;
    int value;

    bool queued;
} Event;

where TimeSpan comes from this library.
After filling the list with some items I run the following function:
bool Events::Save()
{
    // order the elements by the time
    _listEvents.sort(compare);

    // open a file for writing    

    for (int i = 0; i < _listEvents.size(); i++)
    {
        Event *event = _listEvents.get(i);
        // write the item to the file
        writeEvent(file, *event);
    }

    file.close();
    return true;
}

the compare function is defined as follow:
int compare(Event *&ev1, Event *&ev2)
{
    if (ev1->time.hours() > ev2->time.hours()) return true;
    if (ev1->time.hours() < ev2->time.hours()) return false;
    return (ev1->time.minutes() > ev2->time.minutes());
}

It just orders the elements by their time.
This code works fine.
Now I need to handle the queued flag in the struct.
Here a sample input data:



Time
Value
Queued




18:00
1
false


xx:xx
2
true


xx:xx
3
true


10:30
4
false


xx:xx
5
true


08:15
6
false


06:45
7
false



When sorting, the items with the queued flag set must follow the previous item (with queued not set) regardless their time value (hence the xx:xx in the table).
The expected output is:



Time
Value
Queued




06:45
7
false


08:15
6
false


10:30
4
false


xx:xx
5
true


18:00
1
false


xx:xx
2
true


xx:xx
3
true



In other words: if queued is false the elements will be ordered as usual (by their time), if is true they must follow the previous element (like they are "grouped" together).
Since the compare function can just handle two items and I have no other information beyond the initial order, how can I keep the queued items with their "parent" item?

You have to change your definition of what an item is. In this case an item is the non-queued event, plus all the following queued events. So the data structure you sort should consist of those items not of the events you are currently sorting.

Copy the timestamp of the queued event from its parent, and add queued to the compare function.

are the elements with queued == false already in the desired order in the unsorted list?

@463035818_is_not_an_ai no, they can be in arbitrary order

@n.m.couldbeanAI this is feasible, but is it guaranteed the initial order of the queued items then?

Yes, std::list::sort is stable.

Not an answer to your question, but your for-loop is suspicious. Surely LinkedList provides an idiomatic way to iterate on its elements? Iterating on for (int i = 0; i < _listEvents.size(); i++) and then using _listEvents.get(i) repeatedly within the loop probably has a quadratic complexity, assuming get(i) has to iterate on the linked list to find element i.

Beware of using the linked list class you linked to. It does not respect the rule of 3/5/0.

Also, the library you're getting TimeSpan from is written in C++ but typedefs structs, which is patently unnecessary in C++.

@Stef the LinkedList class linked to does not provide any form of iterator.

@Chris Yeah, I looked at the source code and it looks like the only way to loop on it is by keeping a pointer to a ListNode, which is awkward because struct ListNode looks like it was not meant to be part of the public interface.

First group your list. In your example, [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7] becomes [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7]].
Then sort those by the timestamp of the first element in each group. [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7]] becomes [[7], [6], [4, 5], [1, 2, 3]].
Then flatten that list to get [7, 6, 4, 5, 1, 2, 3].
Using std::vector, this might look something like the following (minus the flattening step).
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

struct Event {
    std::string time;
    int value;
    bool queued;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Event> events {
        {"18:00", 1, false},
        {"xx:xx", 2, true},
        {"xx:xx", 3, true},
        {"10:30", 4, false},
        {"xx:xx", 5, true},
        {"08:15", 6, false},
        {"06:45", 7, false}
    };

    std::vector<std::vector<Event>> grouped;

    for (auto &e : events) {
        if (!e.queued) grouped.emplace_back();

        grouped.back().push_back(e);
    }

    for (auto &g : grouped) {
        std::cout << "Group:\n";

        for (auto &e : g) {
            std::cout << e.value << "\n";
        }
    }

    std::sort(
        grouped.begin(), grouped.end(),
        [](auto &g1, auto &g2) {
            return g1[0].time < g2[0].time;
        }
    );

    std::cout << "\nAfter sorting\n\n";

    for (auto &g : grouped) {
        std::cout << "Group:\n";

        for (auto &e : g) {
            std::cout << e.value << "\n";
        }
    }
}

With output:
Group:
1
2
3
Group:
4
5
Group:
6
Group:
7

After sorting

Group:
7
Group:
6
Group:
4
5
Group:
1
2
3


How can I group the list? Should I use nested linked lists?

Use whatever collection data structure you like. In C++, linked lists are often not thought highly of, with preference going to things like std::vector.
